# $(...).fancybox is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to run the jQuery fancybox tool and I keep running into the same problem.  The Firebug debugger highlights the first snippet of jQuery code and says that "$(...).fancybox is not a function".  Here is the basic code that I am trying to run this with. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FancyBox Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="images/1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Sample title 1">
            <img src="images/1.jpg"  width="150" height="100">
        </a>
        <a href="images/2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Sample title 1">
             <img src="images/2.jpg"  width="150" height="100">
        </a>
        <a href="images/3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Sample title 1">
            <img src="images/3.jpg"  width="150" height="100">
        </a>
        <a href="images/4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Sample title 1">
            <img src="images/4.jpg"  width="150" height="100">
        </a>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the links to your scripts, and you're sure they are loaded etc.

Comment: I second @Josh. Are sure that the fancybox/ directory is under the root of the site? Usually, this is placed inside a /js directory.

Comment: Open the console and see if the script has loaded. Get Firebug if you use Firefox, it's great.

Comment: Like others have stated, make sure the fancybox script is loading.  Maybe try using a relative src destination and not one that originates from the root.  I'd guess your path is just wrong.  Aside from checking the console, you can also open up the page source and click on the .js, pulling up either the script or a 404 error.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding following code in your Page HTML header. (Before Fancybox function is called)

```
<script type="text/java script">
 var $= jquery.noConflict();
</script>
```